# How to make form bound inside Django UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a view deriving from `UpdateView` like this:

views.py

```
class MyMixin(object):
    
  def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs = super(MyMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs['request'] = self.request
       return kwargs


class MyView(MyMixin, UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=pk)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/3/$', views.MyView.as_view(), name='...'),
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
```

After the post request, I see nothing happen. No errors and no redirection to success_url. I tried to debug, and turns out that the form is unbound. To check this, I put a breakpoint on the system file `edit.py` that looks like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then checked for validity.
    """
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: A form is bounded in case of a POST request, since then it will use `request.POST` and `request.FILES`. A bounded form does not mean that you use an instance, that is normally done automatically

Comment: I have updated the question. It is a post request

Comment: but exactly why do you think the form is unbounded? Exactly how did you "test" this?

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: you did not by any chance have also patched the `get_form_kwargs` method, etc.? Can you make a code fragment that can *reproduce* the problem. Right now it looks like you share certain fragments, but perhaps not enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Yes ! I have the `get_form_kwargs` overloaded. See the updated question again

Comment: does your `form` has an `__init__` to "accept" the `request`? I know this is getting a bit annoying, but it looks like there is some sort of mismatch between a caller and a callee. Can you share the `__init__` of your `MyForm`?

Comment: can you share the `__init__` of the `MyForm`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem actually, I forgot to pass on the *args and **kwargs to the `__init__` method :(

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar situation and this helped make it work.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form
```